# Scroll to bottom of SectionList with a lot of data in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

So I have a SectionList with data pulled from the User's contacts.  Right next to it is a list of the Alphabet with the first letters of the contacts they have. When they click on a letter it is meant to scroll and bring them to that section.  Much like how the native Iphone contacts screen works.

My issue is that a user could have very many contacts so I cannot set a initialNumToRender.  If the user has a bunch of contacts and they click Z, it hasnt rendered yet and I get the error that I have to use `onScrollToIndexFailed` or `getItemLayout`.  But I have no idea how to use either of these properties to scroll to where I need it to.  Here is the component

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
        
        <SectionList
        style={{width:'90%'}}
        ref={scrollRef}
        
        sections={formattedData}
        renderItem={({item}) => props.renderItem(item)}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <Text
            style={textStyle}>
                 {title}
            </Text>
        )}
        />

        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={alphabetStyle}>
            {formattedData?.length && formattedData.map((e,i) => {
                return(
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=>{
                        scrollRef.current.scrollToLocation({sectionIndex: i, itemIndex: 0})
                    }}>
                        <Text style={titleStyle}>{e.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            })}
        </ScrollView>



    </View>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to /u/Nielrien on reddit.com,

They use the 'react-native-section-list-get-item-layout' package. The hook provided by that package is used to calculate the value of the getItemLayout attribute for the SectionList with the render item element's height and the section header's height

https://snack.expo.dev/@martymfly/sectionlist